# How to get the value in a div on a radio button click?

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

I had tried to get the value in a div(that value is getting from an array) on a radio button click.How can I get the value?

```
fn(){
value
}
{id1 && id1.map(list =>
<div style={{padding:'6px 6px'}}> 
  {"ClaimID:"+ list.ID+' '+'-'+"PatientID:"+list.RCID+' '+'-'+' '+"Amount:" +new Intl.NumberFormat('en-USD', {currency: 'USD' ,style: 'currency'}).format(Number(list.Amount))} 
 <input type='radio' name={'PatientID: ' + list.RCID} vlaue={'PatientID: ' + list.RCID} style={{width: '50px'}} />  </div>)}
```

[image: like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Your question is not clear but i think you can use this code :

```
state = {
  selectedRadioValue: null
}

changeRadioButton = (e) => {
  if(e.target.value == true){
    this.setState({
      selectedRadioValue : e.target.value
    })
  }
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <input type='radio' onChange= {(e) => {this.changeRadioButton(e)}}/>
      <input type='radio' onChange= {(e) => {this.changeRadioButton(e)}}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The values are dynamic and it is from an arrray, we can't assign the value as hardcode

Comment: @JaneFred I've just edited my answer , check it out